# Limit of a geometric summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to solve the following:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{nt} \frac{1}{n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{k-1}.
$$

I think I was able to get the summation correct (see below):

$$
\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{nt+1}}{1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)}.
$$

However, I am unsure of how to take the limit to infinity of the above summation. I know the answer is supposed to be $1 - e^{-t}$ but I am unsure how to arrive at that.

Comment: What is "nt" in the summation?

Comment: Your second displayed  expression simplifies to $1-(1-{t\over nt})^{nt+1}$. I think the power of the $ 1-{1\over n} $ upstairs should be $nt$, not $nt+1$, though. Note $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1+{\theta\over k})^k=e^\theta$.

Comment: Just a term we are summing up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the technicality that $nt$ may not be an integer, the sum is, for $t>0$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{nt} {\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigl(1-{\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigr)^{k-1}=
{1\over n}{1-(1-{1\over n})^{(nt+1)-1}\over 1-(1-{1\over n})} =1-(1-{\textstyle{1\over n}})^{nt}.
$$

So,
$$\eqalign{
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty } \sum_{k=1}^{nt} {\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigl(1-{\textstyle{1\over n}}\bigr)^{k-1}&=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\bigl[\,1-(1-\textstyle{1\over n})^{nt}\,\bigr]\cr
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\bigl[\,1-(1-\textstyle{t\over t n})^{nt}\,\bigr]\cr
&=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty }\bigl[\,1-(1-\textstyle{t\over k})^{k}\,\bigr]\cr
&=1-e^{-t}.
}
$$

We really shouldn't ignore the fact that $nt$ may not be an integer, the sum should actually
be expressed by $1-(1-{\textstyle{1\over n}})^{\lbrack nt\rbrack}$, say, where $[nt]$ is the integer part of $nt$.

Using the fact that
$$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1+{\textstyle{t\over k}})^{k+\alpha}=
\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\bigl[\,(1+{\textstyle{t\over k}})^{k }(1+{\textstyle{t\over k}})^{\alpha }\,\bigr]=e^t,
$$
and the squeeze theorem, one can show 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\bigl  (1-\textstyle{1\over n}\bigr)^{[nt]} =e^{-t}.
$$